# How to get a parent category Name and ID in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am in need of a help from you all. I am stuck in one place. If I am clicking on the sub category of my custom post type I am unable to get a parent category Name and ID.

I have used the below code to get a ID of a child or a parent.

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$myid = $category->term_id;
```

The Issue is now I am not getting a parent category Name
for example
list of categories are

```
Dogs
>> Labrador
>> Pug
Cats
>> small Cats
>> Big Cats
```

Now My question is If I click on Pug it should show me that Pug is in "Dog Category" and ID of dog category is "XXX"

I will be very thankful to you if you help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
 $get_parent_cats = array(
            'parent' => '0' //get top level categories only
        ); 

        $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories 

        foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){
            //for each category, get the ID
            $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

            echo '<li><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $catID ) . ' ">' . $single_category->name . '</a>'; //category name & link
            $get_children_cats = array(
                'child_of' => $catID //get children of this parent using the catID variable from earlier
            );

            $child_cats = get_categories( $get_children_cats );//get children of parent category
            echo '<ul class="children">';
                foreach( $child_cats as $child_cat ){
                    //for each child category, get the ID
                    $childID = $child_cat->cat_ID;

                    //for each child category, give us the link and name
                    echo '<a href=" ' . get_category_link( $childID ) . ' ">' . $child_cat->name . '</a>';

                }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        } //end of categories logic
```

Comment: This is not working I need to show a parent category on bases of sub category. This is giving me a list of all parent categories.

Comment: You want sub category using get parent category?

Comment: No I want parent category name and ID using sub category ID

Comment: Try this  $categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);

Comment: foreach ($categories as $c) {echo '<li>'.$c->cat_name.'</li>';}